# Is there a way to make HTTP request/response not to linger around in Java heap with Jetty?

Tags: java, http, https, glassfish, jetty

Jetty is used as a embedded servlet container running on Glassfish JEE server.

Capturing core dump shows HTTP Post request/response with entire header still lying around in the memory.

Is there a way to clear these requests/responses from the memory?

Comment: Short answer "No". At any give points there will be requests/responses in the memory.

Comment: This question is confusing.  Running Jetty on Glassfish JEE??

Answer (score 0):

If you run *just* Jetty, and not Glassfish, you can provide your own `ByteBufferPool` that clears (sets to all 0) the `ByteBuffer`'s that are returned to the pool.

However you'll take a performance hit doing this.